# Minimization of App Data(android) in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to develop an app for GPS tracking in cordova for android users which also includes android 2.3, they might have very less internal memory. So I want to reduce my app size as much as possible.

The only external resource I am using is google maps API. Yet, my app data is over 3 Mb. I searched in google but, I couldn't find. Can anyone give some guidance to reduce my app data. I would like to  know where can I find the detail description of what does this app data contains of.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, whatever Cordova receives is cached into `app_webview/Cache` and dunno why, but there isn't something which controls this well.

This plugin should help you clear the data: https://github.com/Sharinglabs/cordova-plugin-cache. It is compatible with Cordova 3.3.1 and above. It works with my Cordova 4.2.0 app.